# How to run a function declared in jsp from a button click

Tags: java, function, jsp, button, click

i'm trying to run a function that i declared in jsp (<%! %>) when i click on a button. i don't want to load a new page, i'd like to stay on the same page and just execute something.

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1" import="hitchhike.*"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Loading Route</title>
</head>
<body>
<%! 
    String login;
    String adresseOrigin;
    String adresseDestination;
    Adresse origin;
    Adresse destination;
    Itineraire itineraire;
%>
<%
    login=request.getParameter("login");
    adresseOrigin=request.getParameter("inputOrigin");
    adresseDestination=request.getParameter("inputDestination");
    origin=new Adresse(adresseOrigin);
    destination=new Adresse(adresseDestination);
    origin.generateAdresse();
    destination.generateAdresse();
    itineraire=new Itineraire(origin, destination);
    itineraire.calculItineraire();
%>
<%=origin.getAdresse() %>
</br>
<%=destination.getAdresse() %>
</br>
<%=itineraire.getTemps() %>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="valider()">Validate</button>
</body>
</html>
<%!
void valider(){
    RouteDAO routeDAO=new RouteDAO();
    Route route=new Route(login, 
            origin.getAdresse(), 
            ""+origin.getcoordX(), 
            ""+origin.getCoordY(), 
            destination.getAdresse(),
            ""+destination.getcoordX(),
            ""+destination.getCoordY(),
            itineraire.getTempsSec()
            );
    routeDAO.addRoute(route);
}
    %>
```

this is my code, the function i'd like to run is the one at the end ( valider() ). but when i click on the button i have the error  "valider is not defined"
i'd rather not add jquery.

thanks for helping me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The onclick event can only be tied to a JS/ Jquery function and the code  in `<%! ... %>` gets compiled into java (backend code).

You will have to move the function into another JSP/ backend java code make an AJAX call as part of the onclick event function.

Create a new JSP, say validator.jsp at the same directory level. 
validator.jsp would have:

```
<%!
    RouteDAO routeDAO=new RouteDAO();
    Route route=new Route(login, 
            origin.getAdresse(), 
            ""+origin.getcoordX(), 
            ""+origin.getCoordY(), 
            destination.getAdresse(),
            ""+destination.getcoordX(),
            ""+destination.getCoordY(),
            itineraire.getTempsSec()
            );
    routeDAO.addRoute(route);
%>
```

add a JS, JQuery function in the actual JSP like this:

```
function validator() {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'validator.jsp',  // Change the relative path if needed 
        type: "GET", // This is optional and defaults to GET as well
        error : function(){ 
            console.log('Error in the AJAX call'); 
        },
        success: function(msg){      
                console.log(msg);
        }
}
```

Comment: Adding Java code in JSP is not a good practice. Check if it can be moved into a backend java class and hit the controller URL as part of the AJAX call.